# Joomsport is not working fully with joomla 3.2 blank template

Tags: jquery, css, joomla, mootools, typeerror

So i have this localhost site with Joomla 3.2 and joomsport 2.0.2. When i begin to edit it it was fine. But when i try to view the team stuff it get's broken. My english very bad so please try to understand my problem.

So this is what happens when i click on team name:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElements' grid.js:79
Class.getHeaders grid.js:79
e.extend.$owner mootools-core.js:38
Class.initialize grid.js:58
(anonymous function) mootools-more.js:27
e.extend.$owner mootools-core.js:38
(anonymous function) mootools-core.js:37
(anonymous function) 1?Itemid=:194
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'adopt' slimbox.js:6
(anonymous function) slimbox.js:6
(anonymous function) mootools-core.js:121
(anonymous function) mootools-core.js:5
Array.implement.each mootools-core.js:9
invoke.fireEvent mootools-core.js:120
j
```

After when i click on some of the tabs it shows this:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined 1?Itemid=:181
show_etabs 1?Itemid=:181
onclick
```

So what should i do? i've been searching for google about 3 4 hours and this is my final. So please guys help me out with this. I know a little about html and css. But not so much about jquery so...

grid.js

```
/**


 * @name Grid


 * @author Rick Hopkins


 * @classDescription


 * Sort table data


 * MIT-style License.


 */





var Grid = new Class({


    /** define some variables */


    table: false, 


    headers: false, 


    data: false, 





    /**


     * Initialize the object


     */


    initialize: function(table){


        this.table = table;


        this.getHeaders();


    }, 





    /**


     * Get the headers


     */


    getHeaders: function(){


        this.headers = this.table.getElements('thead tr th');


        this.headers.each(function(h, index){


            //h.store('asc', false);


            if (h.hasClass('sort')) h.addEvent('click', function(){


                if(h.hasClass('asc')){


                    h.className = 'sort desc down';





                    //h.addClassName('desc');


                }else{


                    h.className = 'sort asc';


                    //h.addClassName('asc');


                }


                //if (h.retrieve('asc')) h.store('asc', false);


                //else h.store('asc', true);


                //this.sort($('tblrank_id'));


                this.sort(index);


            }.bind(this));


        }, this);


    }, 





    /**


     * Get the table data


     */


    getData: function(){


        this.data = this.table.getElements('tbody tr');


    }, 





    /**


     * Sort the data


     * @param int index


     */


    sort: function(index){


        this.getData();


        data = [];


        sortType = this.headers[index].getProperty('axis');





        asc = this.headers[index].hasClass('asc');//this.headers[index].retrieve('asc');


        if (this.data.length > 0) this.data.each(function(row, i){


            cells = row.getElements('td');


            if (cells.length < this.headers.length) return false;


            value = cells[index].innerHTML;





            if(cells[index].childNodes[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a"){


                //alert(cells[index].childNodes[0].innerHTML);


                value = cells[index].childNodes[0].innerHTML;


            }
            if(cells[index].childNodes[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "img"){
                if(cells[index].childNodes[1].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "p"){
                    if(cells[index].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a"){

                        value = cells[index].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].innerHTML;

                    }
                }
            }


            if (sortType == 'int' || sortType == 'float'){


                if (value.contains('$') || value.contains(',')) value = value.replace(/\$/g, '').replace(/,/g, '').toFloat();


                else value = value.toFloat();


            } else if (sortType == 'date') value = Date.parse(value);


            data.push({'index': i, 'value': value, 'row': row});


        }, this);





        if (sortType == 'int' || sortType == 'float' || sortType == 'date') data.sort(this.sortNumeric);


        else data.sort(this.sortCaseInsensitive);


        if (!asc) data.reverse();





        this.data = [];


        data.each(function(d, i){


            this.data.push(d.row);


        }, this);





        this.data.each(function(row, i){


            if (row.hasClass('gray')) row.removeClass('gray');


            if (row.hasClass('yellow')) row.removeClass('yellow');


            this.table.getElement('tbody').adopt(row.addClass((i % 2 == 0 ? 'gray' : 'etblraw1')));


        }, this);


    }, 





    /**


     * Sort Numerica Values


     * @param object a


     * @param object b


     */


    sortNumeric: function(a, b){


        /*if ($type(a.value) != 'number') a.value = 0;


        if ($type(b.value) != 'number') b.value = 0;*/


        return parseInt(a.value) - parseInt(b.value);


    }, 





    sortCaseInsensitive: function(a, b){


        a.value = a.value.toLowerCase();
        a.value = a.value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/g, '');

        b.value = b.value.toLowerCase();
        b.value = b.value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/g, '');

        if (a.value == b.value) return 0;


        if (a.value < b.value) return -1;


        return 1;


    }


});
```

Update### - I tried fresh joomla install and joomsport on localhost and it works fine. There is something wrong with javascript or blank template that i edited. This is so killing my time. Please guys help me.

Comment: <script src="/site/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/site/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script> i thought that it's loaded from this system directory

Comment: Can you add `alert(MooTools.version);` in your code and see what you get? It should look __[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/fREgx/)__

Comment: Yes it says 1.4.5 and i think i'll do all the things from the beginning. It's so frustrating. Can you help me on this if upload it?

Comment: Yes, put it online and paste the link here so we can help more.